# setting the k8s cluster to use the hostname/IP address instead of localhost

Tags: kubernetes

I just installed k8s cluster but the URLs are all using localhost and would like to change it to use the hostname or even IP address. Due to this the cluster can be accessed only from the master node. I am unable to find the right place to make this change. Any help is really appreciated.

```
OS: Redhat 7.1
Kubernetes version: 1.2

[rakeshk@ kubernetes]$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080
Elasticsearch is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/elasticsearch-logging
Heapster is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
Kibana is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kibana-logging
KubeDNS is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
kubedash is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubedash
kubernetes-dashboard is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
Grafana is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana
InfluxDB is running at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb
```

Comment: What cluster creation guide did you follow?

Comment: Used [Contrib/Ansible scripts](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib). Running kubernetes 1.2 on Redhat 7.1.

Comment: What did you put into the inventory file? Did you put a machine name/ip address for the master or did you put "localhost"?

Comment: It's a multi-node cluster -  have used hostnames for all nodes including master.

Comment: Can you look on one of your nodes and see how the kubelet is configured to talk to the master? Since it's not on the same host, it must be configured to reach the master via the hostname or IP of the master. `kubectl` by default will always look for a master at `localhost:8080` so that's why it happens to work on the master machine. But you should also be able to generate a kubeconfig file on a remote machine that reaches the master via the exposed secure port.

Comment: @RobertBailey the nodes communicate through proxy and putting another proxy in front of the master should work. kubectl can still use the localhost and my question was regarding the URL access. I have seen people publishing the output of 'kubectl cluster-info' and it looks very different than mine where the localhost is replaced by the hostname or IP of the master. If I can get a non-localhost based URL then I can access it through the browser from other machine as well. Currently one has to be on the master to access the pages.

Comment: What proxy are the nodes communicating through? Is there a tunnel / vpn / something else that connects them to the master such that the kubelets talk to localhost:8080 without credentials and the traffic is automatically forwarded to the apiserver? Each node will run a kube-proxy daemon so that pods can automatically reach the master, but the system processes (kubelet and kube-proxy) should be configured to reach the apiserver directly via hostname or ip address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the port number (`8080`, which is the default value of [`--insecure-port`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/) of `kube-apiserver`), I am guessing that you are running the `kubectl cluster-info` command on the same machine where the `kube-apiserver` is running.

If the above assumption is correct, then copy the `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` file (from the machine thats running the `kube-apiserver`) to your local machine `~/.kube/config`. Run `kubectl cluster-info` on your local machine (install [kubectl](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/prereqs/) program on your local machine, if you haven't already). This should give you cluster address as either a hostname or IP address. Whether it shows it as an IP address or a hostname depends on whether a reverse lookup of the IP address resolves a DNS record.

> If you are initialising [[image]kubernetes](/questions/tagged/kubernetes) using [kubeadm](/questions/tagged/kubeadm) program. `kubeadm init` will autodetect the network interface to advertise the master on as the interface with the default gateway. If default gateway IP address is not routable IP address, ensure that you set `--api-advertise-addresses` to a routable IP address.